# NSArray object pass as postdata in ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, asiformdatarequest

I need to post some data to server,I am sending data to server using `ASIFormDataRequest` `POST` request,

Problem is my server will take response like

```
...
members=[{"EmailId":"sandip.kaptan@alphadezine.in","Name":"sandy"},
...
```

and my response created as

```
members="[{\"Name\":\"sandy\",\"EmailId\":\"sandip.kaptan@alphadezine.in\"}]";
```

i am using following to convert my array to

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                   options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

at this point my `jsonString` as print as what i want, but when i add this to `ASIFormDataRequest request`

```
`[request addPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"Members"];`
```

it is added `\` in the value...
so how to overcome with this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Have you Check What your server is getting ?  I guess `\` is added by the `ASIFormDataRequest` to make some internal string conversion. It should send the response without `\`.Your server would have receive the response as you are expecting.

Comment: I have checked it, when i add it to `NSDictionary` than also it add \     :(